# How to keep user signed in longer when using Azure Active Directory (AAD)?

Tags: azure, active-directory

How to ask for the username/password less frequently (than the default 1-hour access token lifetime) when using Azure Active Directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure AD allows you to [configure the lifetime of a token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes).

You can setup a token lifetime policy such that access/id tokens with a lifetime of n hours. There's a few nuances that the doc I linked should walk you through.  For instance, the policy should be linked to the resource not necessarily your web app.